# How to sign exe file using signtool from windows

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing, private-key, signtool

When I try to sign my exe file using signtool from windows, I used this command in a command line:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86>SignTool sign /debug /fd SHA1 /a /f certificate.crt xone.exe
```

But I got this:

```
The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: ***********
    Issued by: ZeroSSL RSA Domain Secure Site CA
    Expires:   Sat May 28 01:59:59 2022
    SHA1 hash: 71A05C21AC6C48EB5C253811D9E66D7E3D2443B2

After EKU filter, 0 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 0 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: **Your certificate is a certificate for SSL-aka-TLS communication, not for code-signing.** CAs are required to follow different procedures for code-signing  than for SSL/TLS, and for _Microsoft_ code-signing in particular also to use different roots.